# Docker Compose up -d for wordpress just returns one line

Tags: docker, wordpress

I am attempting to run `docker-compose up -d` on a wordpress `docker-compose.yml` configuration from the official docs on dockers website. It doesn't run anything it just returns the following `wordpress_db_1 is up-to-date
wordpress_wordpress_1 is up-to-date`

Here is my configuration

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

This is the documentation I am following https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

I checked to see if wordpress happened to be running on localhost:8000 as it says it will and nothing.

I just went and reset docker to factory settings then ran the same command again and this is the result, however still nothing running on `localhost:8000`

```
PS C:\Users\andersk\sites\wordpress> docker-compose up -d
Creating network "wordpress_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "wordpress_db_data" with default driver
Pulling db (mysql:5.7)...
5.7: Pulling from library/mysql
a5a6f2f73cd8: Pull complete
936836019e67: Pull complete
283fa4c95fb4: Pull complete
1f212fb371f9: Pull complete
e2ae0d063e89: Pull complete
5ed0ae805b65: Pull complete
0283dc49ef4e: Pull complete
a7905d9fbbea: Pull complete
cd2a65837235: Pull complete
5f906b8da5fe: Pull complete
e81e51815567: Pull complete
Pulling wordpress (wordpress:latest)...
latest: Pulling from library/wordpress
a5a6f2f73cd8: Already exists
633e0d1cd2a3: Pull complete
fcdfdf7118ba: Pull complete
4e7dc76b1769: Pull complete
c425447c8835: Pull complete
75780b7b9977: Pull complete
33ed51bc30e8: Pull complete
7c4215700bc4: Pull complete
d4f613c1e621: Pull complete
de5465a3fde0: Pull complete
6d373ffaf200: Pull complete
991bff14f001: Pull complete
d0a8c1ecf326: Pull complete
aa3627a535bb: Pull complete
a36be75bb622: Pull complete
98ebddb8e6ca: Pull complete
ed6e19b74de1: Pull complete
18b9cc4a2286: Pull complete
dfe625c958ac: Pull complete
Creating wordpress_db_1 ... done
Creating wordpress_wordpress_1 ... done
```

When I run `docker-machine ip MACHINE_VM` I get the following returned 
`Docker machine "MACHINE_VM" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.`

And Lastly when I run `docker-machine ls` as it asks I just get `NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS` returned

Answer (score 0):

This was so stupid, I had copied this `docker-composer.yml` from here https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/ and then followed the instructions from here https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/ and they have set different ports one `8080` and one `8000` so I was just typing in `8000` in my browser and it was set to `8080` omg so stupid.